# Processing video frame by frame using opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
count = 0

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc("drop.avi")
out = cv2.VideoWriter('drop.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while True:
   # Capture frame-by-frame
   ret, frame = cap.read()

   # Our operations on the frame come here
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   name = "frame%d.jpg"%count   # save frame as JPEG file
   cv2.imwrite(name,frame)


   # Display the resulting frame
   cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
   if cv2.waitKey(10):
      break
```

Comment: I receive TypeError: Required argument 'c2' (pos 2) not found when I run the code. I want to run a video file then capture pictures from frames of the video.

Comment: your fourcc is wrong. should be like: `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')`

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Answer (score 4):

You are specifying your foucc wrong.

```
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID') 
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter("drop.avi", fourcc, 20, (640,480))
```

see [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) for more info

Comment: Thank you. I replace those lines with fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc("drop.avi")
out = cv2.VideoWriter('drop.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))  respectively and I received   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'

Comment: What verison of open cv are you using? cv2.__version__ in python terminal after importing open cv.